# maven test cannot find resources

Tags: testing, maven, resources

I am trying to do maven test.

I have set resource directory

```
<testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

I put a folder called inbound inside this directory.
In my junit, I am trying to open it as new File("Inbound"), but it always cannot find it.
I have have a inbound copy under my project root. The junit code cannot find it.
Could any one please give me some suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you use `src/test/resources`, then you don't have to specify it in your `pom.xml` as it is the default resources path for tests.

Regarding your problem, you should not use `new File("myfile");` but `MyTestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myfile");` instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. but I need to know the correct path. I'd like to open it as a folder not just a file

Comment: The `File` class in Java is just a path-name.  It can refer to a file **or** a directory.  The referred "file" need not even exist.  If `aFile = new File("Inbound")` then `aFile.isDirectory()` will evaluate to `true`.  See Javadocs for the `File` class at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add it into your `src/test/resources`

2) when load use `classpath:YOUR_FILE`

PS: you do not need to specify that code in your pom.xml, those folders are maven defaults.